# How to fill array list in

Tags: c#

I'm new with c# so hope anyone can help me.
I have this code, how can I get my array list instead of this

```
"Length", "Color", "CHEESE", "Vesa", "none"
```

.

```
ArrayList props = new ArrayList();
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        //txt += row["Txt1"].ToString();
        props.Add(string.Join(",", row.ItemArray.Select(item => item.ToString())));
    }

    data.AddRange(new string[] { "Length", "Color", "CHEESE", "Vesa", "none"  });
```

Comment: What is `data`? and what is exactly wrong with your code ? Why are you using `ArrayList` instead of the Generic `List<string>`? . I understand you might be coming from Java, but you may need to read some C# book to start with.

Comment: You can also replace the whole loop with: `List<string> props = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => String.Join(",", x.ItemArray.Select(i => i.ToString()))).ToList();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As much I can understand from your code, you are trying to fill arraylist from dataTable. You can use LINQ to fill your Arraylist.
If you really want to use ArrayList you can try this:

```
ArrayList props = new ArrayList();
props.AddRange(
              (from a in dt select new{string.Join(",", a.ItemArray.Select(item =>item.ToString()))})
              .ToList());
```

Otherwise I will suggest you to use Generic List.

Answer (score 1):

```
        string[] wordsFirstExample = new string[5] { "Length", "Color", "CHEESE", "Vesa", "none" };

        List<string> wordsSecondExsample = new List<string>();
        wordsSecondExsample.Add("Length");
        wordsSecondExsample.Add("Color");
```

in wordsFirstExample I created array of strings with all ur words.
in wordsSeccondExample its a list with all ur words, u can add them one by one with Add() method.